# Python 2.7 installed but no interpreter for CLI?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I just had my sever provider install Ubuntu 15.1.0 on a new server. I need Python 2.7.11 running on the server for an app I want to deploy there. I ran `apt --installed list` and see that I have a number of Python packages installed:

```
dh-python/wily,wily,now 2.20150826ubuntu1 all [installed]
libpython2.7/wily,wily,now 2.7.10-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpython2.7-minimal/wily,wily,now 2.7.10-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpython2.7-stdlib/wily,wily,now 2.7.10-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpython3-stdlib/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libpython3.4-minimal/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libpython3.4-stdlib/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python-apt-common/wily-updates,wily-updates,now 1.0.1ubuntu0.1 all [installed]
python3/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python3-apt/wily-updates,wily-updates,now 1.0.1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
python3-dbus/wily,wily,now 1.2.0-2build3 amd64 [installed]
python3-distupgrade/wily-updates,wily-updates,now 1:15.10.14.4 all [installed]
python3-gdbm/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-4 amd64 [installed]
python3-gi/wily,wily,now 3.16.2-1build1 amd64 [installed]
python3-minimal/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python3-six/wily,wily,now 1.9.0-5 all [installed]
python3-update-manager/wily,wily,now 1:15.10.3 all [installed]
python3.4/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python3.4-minimal/wily,wily,now 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

I'm not sure what most of these are. Now, my problem is I want to have `python` on the command line use Python 2.7.x. Right now, `python` refers to nothing (`-bash: python: command not found`). Same with `python2` and `python2.7`. However, it appears - based on the list above - that Python 2.7.x is indeed installed.

`python3` works correctly, but starts Python 3.4.x and I need 2.7.x

**EDIT:** For reference, `whereis python` returns:

```
python: /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.4 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.4
```

Comment: Looks like you have python 3.4 there in /usr/bin . You probably need to install 2.7 manually

Answer (score 0):

You have packages for Python 2.7 libraries, but not for the interpreter. Installing the package `python` should install `python2.7` as a dependency, which contains the interpreter for Python 2.7.